# how to use Linq to get a sitecore field

Tags: c#, linq, sitecore

I have a search that I'm wanting to exclude any search result that has the name of the "Title" field in the search. For example, say I type in "Contact" in the search bar. I don't want the Contact Us page to come up, but if someone wants to search something that has words in the Contact Us page, then its ok. I am able to get templateName and IDs but can't seem to get fields...

```cs
Item homeItem = Main.Utilities.SitecoreUtils.getHomeItem();

var query = PredicateBuilder.True<SearchResultItem>();
query = query.And(i => i.Paths.Contains(homeItem.ID));
query = query.And(i => i.Content.Contains(searchTerm));
query = query.And(i => i.TemplateName != "MenuFolder");
```

This is what I have, but I want to add something to it to exclude the "Title" field and maybe the "SEO" field. So probably something like:

```cs
query = query.And(i => i.Fields["Title"];
```

But in this case its including not excluding it. And I can't do:

```cs
query = query.And(i != i.Fields["Title"];
```

It won't accept that answer.

Comment: do you mean something like `i => !i["Title"].Contains(searchTerm)`?

Comment: yes that will work :) write it out and i'll accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use code like that `i => !i["Title"].Contains(searchTerm)`:

```cs
Item homeItem = Main.Utilities.SitecoreUtils.getHomeItem();

var query = PredicateBuilder.True<SearchResultItem>();
query = query.And(i => i.Paths.Contains(homeItem.ID));
query = query.And(i => i.Content.Contains(searchTerm));
query = query.And(i => i.TemplateName != "MenuFolder");

query = query.And(i => !i["Title"].Contains(searchTerm));
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to strongly type it, you just need to extend the SearchResultItem class with your field name.

```
public class SitecoreItem : SearchResultItem
{
[IndexField("title")]        
public string Title { get; set; }

[IndexField("__smallcreateddate")]
public DateTime PublishDate { get; set; }

[IndexField("has_presentation")]
public bool HasPresentation { get; set; }

}
```

Then your code would be like this

```
IQueryable<SitecoreItem> query = context.GetQueryable<SitecoreItem>();

SearchResults<SitecoreItem> results = null;
query = query.Where(x => x.Title.Contains(searchText);

results = query.GetResults();
```