# excluding templates from search in sitecore

Tags: c#, linq, sitecore

I can't seem to get this to work. I started with [how to use Linq to get a sitecore field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36403166/how-to-use-linq-to-get-a-sitecore-field) but have stalled. I'm trying to exclude certain pages/templates. Here is what I have:

```
var query = PredicateBuilder.True<SearchResultItem>();
query = query.And(i => i.Paths.Contains(homeItem.ID));
query = query.And(i => i.Content.Contains(searchTerm));
query = query.And(i => i.TemplateName != "MenuFolder");
query = query.And(i => i["Template"] != "/sitecore/templates/Common/Folder");
```

The last one, with the path "/sitecore/templates/Common/Folder", I can't get to work. I want to make sure that when a search is performed that none of the folders come up in the search. I've used variations of Path, Paths, TemplateName, TemplateID, but I can't seem to make it work.

Comment: Are you sure the field is called "Template" and not something else?

Comment: the field isn't called template, thats just the name under "Quick Info" giving it where the folder came from

Comment: If I am getting this right, you want to exclude all folders based on Common /Folder template, correct? Then the easiest way is to do a i.TemplateID != Sitecore.TemplateIDs.Folder. 

Sitecore has classes like Sitecore.IDs and Sitecore.TemplateIDs for system items where you can get the IDs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to do the following:

```
var query = PredicateBuilder.True<SearchResultItem>();
query = query.And(i => i.Paths.Contains(homeItem.ID));
query = query.And(i => i.Content.Contains(searchTerm));
query = query.And(i => i.TemplateName != "MenuFolder");
query = query.And(i => i.TemplateId != Sitecore.TemplateIDs.Folder);
```

The Sitecore.TemplateIDs.Folder is the ID of the folder in the path `/sitecore/templates/Common/Folder` and its ID is `{A87A00B1-E6DB-45AB-8B54-636FEC3B5523}`

Thanks